# Android CTS test case "android.view.cts.DisplayRefreshRateTest#testRefreshRate" failed

Tags: android, gpu, cts

I am working on a Freescale i.MX6Q based board.

When I'm running CTS test case "android.view.cts.DisplayRefreshRateTest#testRefreshRate" on Android 4.0.4, it worked but failed when it's on Android 4.2.2.

I checked the logcat massage. It claimed that the display fps is 60. In fact, it's 52.

Below is logcat message:

```
D/DisplayRefreshRateTest( 3535): claimed 60.000004 fps, achieved 51.89083 fps </p>
D/DisplayRefreshRateTest( 3535): restarting
D/DisplayRefreshRateTest( 3535): claimed 60.000004 fps, achieved 51.141434 fps</p>
D/DisplayRefreshRateTest( 3535): restarting
D/DisplayRefreshRateTest( 3535): claimed 60.000004 fps, achieved 51.157303 fps</p>
D/DisplayRefreshRateTest( 3535): restarting
```

Is it possible that GPU's abiltiy is low on Android 4.2.2 or if there's any other reason cause this problem.

The below link is whole logcat massage when running CTS. monitor dpi 1080p, 60HZ, HDMI

*https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54920228/Logcat.txt*

I'd appreciate any advice to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have HW composer on, from my experience 4.2.2 is definitely an improvement from 4.1 in terms of graphics performance on Freescale.

Do you get this with the prebuilt image from Freescale? You should verify that it happens with their image before running your own.

I assume it passes with lower resolution?